# Leg animation not working

Tags: c#, animation, if-statement, xna, xna-4.0

I am making a simple animation in XNA C# of a leg moving. This is the logic code for the thigh. It is meant to swing from 25' to 335'. However instead, it hits a point and then keeps on spinning in the other direction. Please help, here's the code:

```
    private void Thigh_method()
    {
        if (Legdata.Left == true)
            signvalue = -0.05f;
        else
            signvalue = 0.05f;

        if (Legdata.ToMid == true)
            Thighturn_ang += signvalue;
        if (Legdata.ToMid == false)
            Thighturn_ang -= signvalue;

        if (Thighturn_ang <= 25 || Thighturn_ang <= 335 && Thighturn_ang <= 180)
            Legdata.Left = true;
        if (Thighturn_ang >= 25 || Thighturn_ang >= 335 && Thighturn_ang >= 180)
            Legdata.Left = false;

        if (Thighturn_ang == 0)
            Legdata.ToMid = false;
        if (Math.Abs(Thighturn_ang) >= 25f)
            Legdata.ToMid = true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance, Yours:

Mona

Comment: it's hard to figure out from provided code, what is happening there. Please provide some transformation code in relation of the question.

Comment: This question might be better suited over at [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Values: 
            `int screenheight;
        int screenwidth;
        float signvalue;
        int count;
        float Thighturn_ang;

        Vector2 Thightop_pos;
        Vector2 Kneepoint_pos;
            Thightop_pos = new Vector2(screenwidth / 2, 30);
            Thighturn_ang = 0;
            count = 0;
            Legdata.ToMid = false;
            Legdata.Left = false;`

Comment: What do the `if`-statements with `Thighturn_ang` do? The first one basically reduces to `if(Thighturn_ang <= 180)`. You can't determine the direction from the position. You need to store the velocity in some way.

Comment: You're comparing a floating point value using ==. Not a good idea, due to [floating point inaccuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: @DXsmiley: Thanks I think this is the problem, ill keep this in mind for next time.

Comment: @NicoSchertler : Thnx ill try that.